# How to move physical mouse when two frames present in a page

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

After login in project have one page with two frame.when i try to move mouse using Robot class,mouse don't move from one frame to other frame.also i used selenium code for move one frame to another.

some part of code:

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
driver.switchTo().frame("pageFrame");
GenerateLogFile.logger.info("Click on force auth.");
login.waitForForceAuth();
mouseMoveAction(login.forceAuth());
login.forceAuth().click();
```

**mouseMoveAction** method:

```
public void mouseMoveAction(WebElement element) throws AWTException {
    Point coordinates = element.getLocation();
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.mouseMove(coordinates.getX(), coordinates.getY());
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow Sanadanda, perhaps you should check the [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You can [edit] your question - don't post code in comments next time

Comment: you wrote "also i used selenium code for move one frame to another". Please edit your question, show the code and explain how it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can't mix `Robot` and Selenium. Selenium already has everything that you need to simulate mouse events. On top of that, many WebDrivers don't create any windows (they just render the page in some internal memory area), so Robot has nothing to work with.

Try this code in `mouseMoveAction()`:

```
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(element);
```

Comment: This answer doesn't address the frames issue that OP was talking about.